# Bullet hits block. Show that linear momentum is not conserved

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision

> "..." First, we will familiarize us with a collision between a homogeneous beam of length,
>   $L$, mass $M$ attached with a frictionless hinge in point $O$ at one of the endpoints of
>   the beam. The moment of inertia of the beam for rotations around the point $O$ in the
>   direction given by the hinge is $I$. The beam is macroscopic and aﬀected by gravity.
>   The acceleration of gravity is $g$ in the negative $y$-direction. Initially, the beam hangs
>   straight down in the negative $y$-direction, as illustrated in ﬁgure 0.12. A small bullet
>   of mass $m$ is ﬁred along the $x$-axis, hitting the beam at the bottom. The bullet has
>   an initial velocity $v_0$ and remains lodged in the beam after the collision.

[image]

**One of the exercises is:** Show that the linear momentum of the system is generally not conserved during the collision. In what special case would the linear momentum of the system be conserved?

As $\vec{G}$ is the only external force acting on the system, and it is perpendicular to both the linear velocity $v$ and the angular velocity $\omega$ during the collision, $\vec{G}$ surely does no work.

I'm able to show that $p_o \neq p_1$:
$$ m v_0 = (M + m) \omega r$$
$r = \frac{(1/2M+m)L}{M + m}$ , $\omega = \frac{mv_0 - constant*(1-\cos{\theta_2})}{(1/3M+m)L}$ found in earlier exercises
$$ \Rightarrow m v_0 \neq \frac{2}{3}m v_0$$

Comment: To connect forces to momentum, you should consider *impulse*, not work.

Comment: Here is the full exercise set in case anyone is interested:
[link](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/fys/FYS-MEK1110/v14/materiale/oblig09.pdf)

Comment: The impulse in $y$-direction is 0 anyway, as $G$is counteracted by the force from the hinge, right? And $G$does not affect the $x$-direction as long as $\theta_2 = 0$

Comment: If you have take the image from a text book, you have to reference the book properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hinge, which connects the "system" (bullet and beam) to the outside world does not exert any torque on the system, but it can and does exert both a vertical and horizontal force on the system ***at the moment of impact***.  Consider for a moment if the bullet hit close to the hinge;  the hinge could fail and allow the beam and bullet to move in the direction of the bullet's travel.

I think that a consideration of "center of percussion", http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_percussion, could clarify the situation...

Not that in this article, the hinge is replaced with a sliding U-bolt, which cannot exert horizontal forces...